# Extjs 3 onchange is not working?

Tags: extjs3

I have one textfield in extjs3, In which if i enter 12 digit it should automatically get fire.

we are scanning by barcode scanner, so if digit reach 12 digit it should automatically get fire.

```
listeners: {
  'change': function(field, newValue, oldValue){
    if(  newValue.length ==12 || newValue.length ==13){
           alert("searchByUpcFunction()");
    }
  }
}
```

in extjs 4 same thing is working, but not in extjs 3. I need same thing in extjs 3.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to `keyup` or `valid` events. `change` is fired when you leave the field.

```
listeners: {
  'keyup': function(field, newValue, oldValue){
     // ...
  }
}
```